# negative coefficient of predictor in mixed-effects model produces positive slope in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I've fitted a mixed-effect regression model to experimental data using the `lmer()` function in the `lme4` package in `R`.

```
require(lme4)

mod = lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (x1|re1) + (x1|re2), data = dat, REML = FALSE)

summary(mod)

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate   Std. Error     df     t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       7.008e+00   3.318e-02  4.850e+01  211.166  < 2e-16 ***
x1                -6.686e-02  2.028e-02  3.400e+01  -3.297   0.00229 ** 
x2                -4.357e-02  1.313e-02  4.870e+01  -3.318   0.00172 ** 
x3                -5.302e-03  1.373e-02  7.110e+01  -0.386   0.70054
```

Notice that the predictor of interest, `x1`, has a negative coefficient, so I expect the dependent variable to decrease when the predictor of interest increases.

In order to visualize model predictions, I generated model predictions using the `predict()` function.

`dat$preds = predict(mod, dat, type = "response")`

Then I plotted these predictions against the predictor of interest using the `ggplot2` package.

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x1, y=preds)) +
  geom_point(shape=16, cex=1) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm) +
  xlab("x1") + ylab("predicted y") +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=26), axis.text=element_text(size=16))
```

[image: plot of model predictions y' as a function of variable of interest x1]

I was surprised to see that the slope of the function is positive. But how is that possible, given that the coefficient of that predictor in the model is negative? Is there some error in my code or am I wrong in interpreting the estimate of x1 as a negative slope?

Comment: Maybe through your other variables? If `x2` and/or `x3` decrease as `x1` increases. I'm quite surprised by the linearity of your point predictions. You should show your `ggplot` code so we know what's going on. Looks like you might be using `geom_smooth` and fitting a model to your predictions...

Comment: Please provide the code to produce the plot

Comment: If you want to isolate the effect of `x1` you should create a new dataframe containing example values of `x1` only, then predict into that. Then plot using `geom_line()` so that you plot the actual predicted values, not a smoothed/average curve.

Comment: @Gregor @Marius Thanks for your comments! Isn't the problem that the plotted model is not the same model as `mod`? In the plot, I'm fitting a new `lm()` model just between the `x1` and `preds`, which is not the same as `mod` (for one, it doesn't have random effects). Nowhere in the plotting code do I input the actual model data.

Comment: Right. You won't be able to use `geom_smooth` with a multidimensional mixed effects model. So you've indeed correctly identified the problem, and Marius has proposed a good solution. Do you still have a question?

Comment: @Gregor I actually do want to plot the effect of `x1` when `x2` and `x3` are controlled for, to make sure that each explains their real share of variance. Is it precisely when these other variables are present, that the coefficient for `x1` is negative. In practice, this boils down to asking: is there a plotting tool that will plot the results of an lmer() mixed-effects model?

Comment: @Marius That makes sense! Would you be able to provide the full plotting code in the solution? I've tried variants with geom_line() but that didn't work and I didn't know how to include the model as an argument.

Comment: That's not well-defined. You have point-wise predictions in `pred`, you can plot those vs `x1`. Or you can do as Marius suggested (the model controls for `x2` and `x3` and you ignore them in the plot - this will be a straight line with your model intercept and slope equal to the `x1` coefficient). Or you can try to make a contour plot for `x1` and `x2` with your response as the color and ditto with `x3`.

Comment: For the line, the easiest might be `+ geom_abline(intercept = 7.008, slope = -6.686e-02)`